# Equivalence between covariance definitions

Tags: probability, random-variables, expected-value, covariance

Could you tell me why the following definition of the covariance:

$$
Cov(X, Y) = \mathbb{E} \Big[ \big(X - \mathbb{E}[X]\big) \, \big(Y - \mathbb{E}[Y]\big) \Big]
$$

is equivalent to the following one?

$$
Cov(X, Y) = \mathbb{E}[X \, Y] - \mathbb{E}[X] \, \mathbb{E}[Y]
$$

---

EDIT

By expanding, I get:

\begin{align}
Cov(X, Y) &= \mathbb{E}[X \, Y] - \mathbb{E}[X \, \mathbb{E}[Y]] - \mathbb{E}[Y \, \mathbb{E}[X]] + \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X] \, \mathbb{E}[Y]] = \\
&= \mathbb{E}[X \, Y] - \mathbb{E}[Y] \, \mathbb{E}[X] - \mathbb{E}[X] \, \mathbb{E}[Y] + \mathbb{E}[X] \, \mathbb{E}[Y] = \\
&= \mathbb{E}[X \, Y] - \mathbb{E}[Y] \, \mathbb{E}[X]
\end{align}

Comment: Expand the product into 4 terms in the definition of covariance and simplify

Comment: Hello @Golden_Ratio thank you for the suggestion. I edited my question, but I'm stuck.

Comment: Good now use the fact that the expected value is a constant and for any constant $a$ and RV $X$, $E[aX]=aE[X]$

Comment: @Golden_Ratio perfect suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By expanding:

\begin{align}
Cov(X, Y) &= \mathbb{E}[X \, Y] - \mathbb{E}[X \, \mathbb{E}[Y]] - \mathbb{E}[Y \, \mathbb{E}[X]] + \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X] \, \mathbb{E}[Y]] = \\
&= \mathbb{E}[X \, Y] - \mathbb{E}[Y] \, \mathbb{E}[X] - \mathbb{E}[X] \, \mathbb{E}[Y] + \mathbb{E}[X] \, \mathbb{E}[Y] = \\
&= \mathbb{E}[X \, Y] - \mathbb{E}[Y] \, \mathbb{E}[X]
\end{align}